# jQuery and Multiple Forms, only the first one works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with multiple  elements and some jQuery code to send when one of the forms are clicked.

form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="vote" name="vote" type="hidden" value="up">
<input id="post_id" name="post_id" type="hidden" value="{{submission.id}}"/>
<input type="submit" class="arrowup" value=""/>
</form>
```

jQuery javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/button_form/",
                dataType: "json",
                data : {
                    post_id : encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('post_id').value),
                    vote : encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('vote').value),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                success : function(json) {
                        $('#result').html( 'post id: ' + json.post_id + ' voted: ' + json.up_or_down);
                    },
                error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                        alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The first button works as expected and gets the server's json response, however all the other buttons don't work.

I'm led to think this might be because there are multiple vote and post_id form inputs, but can't figure out an alternative strategy, or if that's really the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: if you have multiple forms, then use forms' ids for submit event: ` $("#formID").submit(function(e) {)`

Comment: Yup, it's the duplicate IDs that are likely your problem. They're a bad idea generally. If you can't modify the IDs,  you're going to have to look for the elements within the context of the current form, rather than within the `document` context as you currently are.

Comment: @Reza Makes sense. However, would I now need multiple iterations of the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can iterate through all your forms and submit each one separetely on their submit event:

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',    
    // All other ajax code for submitting form data
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunate that doesn't seem to have worked. The data that gets submitted is still only from the first <form>.

Comment: Try submitting each form by their ID!